# can sub-categories be created in a listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I can't find a way to create sub-categories in a listview, can I do it?

I noticed that the listview customization is very limited.

Comment: Use a nested ListView.

Comment: what's the difference with the classic one?